# Will Oculus Rift work with Quadro M1000M for non-gaming purposes?

Tags: glfw, oculus

On the website of Oculus Rift is is stated that the minimum system requirements for the Oculus Rift are a NVIDIA GTX 970 / AMD R9 290 equivalent or greater. I am aware that the Quadro M1000M does not meet those requirements.

My intention is to use the Oculus Rift for developing educational applications (visualization of molecular structures) which in terms of computational demand does not even come close to modern games.

For the above-mentioned kind of purpose, **would the Oculus Rift run fine on less powerful GPUs (i.e. the Quadro M1000M) or is the driver developed in such a way that it simply "blocks" cards that do not meet the required specifications?**

Further information:

I intent on developing my application in Linux using GLFW in combination with LibOVR as mentioned in this guide: http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.1/rift.html.

**edit**
It was pointed out that the SDK does not support Linux. So as an alternative option, I could also use Windows / Unity.

Any personal experiences on the topic are highly appreciated!

Comment: Oculus SDK does not support Linux.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Thanks. I had the impression though it was still possible as there are some guides on the internet to get it working. Nevertheless, I am also comfortable programming in Windows/Unity. I have changed my question.

Comment: The guides are probably written for a pre-release SDK/Runtime that had Linux support, but the consumer Rift doesn't support it.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Thanks! That would explain it then. So if I would use a Windows setup with Unity, do you think it would still work on a lower end GPU if I would develop the program in such a way that it is computationally cheap?

Comment: Mobile chips such as M1000M are problematic especially if they use Optimus. It varies on case-by-case basis whether they work at all so the first thing would be to make sure that it's compatible and that can reliably be known only by testing on an actual Rift.

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't talking about performance but whether it can even display anything on the headset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question (I hope that's ok), I bought an Oculus Rift CV1. It turns out it runs smoothly on my HP Zbook G3 which has an Quadro M1000M card in it. Admittedly, the Oculus Desktop application gives a warning that my machine does not meet the required specifications. Indeed, if I render a scene with lots of complicated graphics in it and turn my head, the visuals tend to 'stutter' a bit.

I tested a couple of very simple scenes in Unity 5 and these run without any kind of problems. I would say that the above mentioned hardware is perfectly suitable for any kind of educational purposes I had in mind, just nothing extremely fancy.

As @SurvivalMachine mentioned in the comments, Optimus can be a bit problematic, but this is resolved by turning hybrid graphics off in the bios (which I heard is possible for the HP Zbook series, but not for all laptops). Furthermore, the laptop needs to be connected to a power outlet (i.e. not run on its battery) for the graphical card to function properly with the Oculus Rift.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer Oculus Rift hardware has not been reverse engineered to the point where you can use it without the official software, which currently only supports Windows based desktop systems running one of a specific number of supported GPUs.  It will not function on any mobile GPU, nor on any non-Windows OS.  Plugging the HMD into the display port on systems where the Oculus service isn't running will not result in anything appearing on the headset.

The Oculus DK2 and DK1 can both be made to function on alternative operating systems and with virtually any graphics card, since when connected they are detected by the OS as just another monitor.

Basically your only path is to either use older HMD hardware, wait for Oculus to support other platforms, or wait for someone to reverse engineer the interaction with the production HMD hardware.